# Zend_Http_Client Hangs when attempting to request an invalid URL

Tags: php, zend-framework, curl

I am using `Zend_Http_Client` to request an URL, the HTTP client has a timeout set to 10.

```php
$config = array(
    'adapter'   => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl',
    'curloptions' => array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Zend_Curl_Adapter',
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => 0,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 10,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    ),
);
```

For testing I have also added a set time limit to try to stop it from hanging:

```php
set_time_limit(10);

try {
    $client->request($method);
} catch (Zend_Http_Client_Exception $e) {
    // ...
}
```

The request simply hangs, so I can't get a response object and no exceptions / fatals are thrown. Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Found the issue, it is actually an issue with the context, for some reason throwing an exception in a closure is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the [CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option?

Comment: Yes, As in the comment above it wasn't the http_client, it was this that was causing it to hang. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62628